# Ansible form the list or separate the dictionary

Tags: ansible

I have the below dicotionary value

```
{
"1application": "abc",
"2service": "def",
"3service": ghi",
"4application": "jkl",
"5service": "mno",
"6application": "abc",
"7service": "def",
"8service": ghi"
}
```

From this I have to form a list like below, starting from first application to next application I have to form one list, and so on

```
[
"1application": "abc",
"2service": "def",
"3service": ghi",
]
[
"4application": "jkl",
"5service": "mno",
]
[
"6application": "abc",
"7service": "def",
"8service": ghi"
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? What is you question exactly ? There is no question mark anywhere in your post.

Comment: I have to use application name and service name. so i have to split the combined list of application and service like above list... services under first application will have to be in the first list. and services under 2nd application need to be in second list.

Comment: This is a requirement, not a question. So again: what did you try to achieve this requirement and what is your exact problem when you try to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

The playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_dict:
      {"1application": "abc",
       "2service": "def",
       "3service": "ghi",
       "4application": "jkl",
       "5service": "mno",
       "6application": "abc",
       "7service": "def",
       "8service": "ghi"}
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_list: "{{ my_list|default([]) +
                     [dict(my_range_keys|
                           zip(my_range_keys|
                               map('extract', my_dict)))] }}"
      loop: "{{ my_idxs }}"
      loop_control:
        extended: true
      vars:
        my_keys: "{{ my_dict.keys()|list|sort }}"
        my_len: "{{ my_keys|length }}"
        my_apps: "{{ my_keys|select('match', '^(\\d+)application(.*)$')|list }}"
        my_idxs: "{{ my_apps|map('regex_replace', '^(\\d+)(.*)$', '\\1')|list }}"
        my_last: "{{ ansible_loop.nextitem|default(my_len|int + 1) }}"
        my_range: "{{ range(item|int - 1, my_last|int - 1)|list }}"
        my_range_keys: "{{ my_range|map('extract', my_keys)|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_list
```

gives

```yaml
  my_list:
  - 1application: abc
    2service: def
    3service: ghi
  - 4application: jkl
    5service: mno
  - 6application: abc
    7service: def
    8service: ghi
```

---

The previous solution works only with a single-digit prefix. With multiple digits, the `sort` function doesn't work anymore. In this case, we have to create the sorted list of the keys. For example, the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_dict:
      {"1application": "abc",
       "2service": "def",
       "3service": "ghi",
       "4application": "jkl",
       "5service": "mno",
       "6application": "abc",
       "7service": "def",
       "8service": "ghi",
       "9application": "prs",
       "10service": "stu",
       "11service": "vxy"}
  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        my_keys_idx: "{{ my_keys_idx|default([]) +
                         [{'idx': my_idx|int, 'key': item}] }}"
      loop: "{{ my_dict.keys()|list }}"
      vars:
        my_idx: "{{ item|regex_replace('^(\\d+)(.*)$', '\\1') }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_keys_idx

    - set_fact:
        my_keys: "{{ my_keys_idx|
                     sort(attribute='idx')|
                     map(attribute='key')|
                     list }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_keys
```

gives

```yaml
  my_keys:
  - 1application
  - 2service
  - 3service
  - 4application
  - 5service
  - 6application
  - 7service
  - 8service
  - 9application
  - 10service
  - 11service
```

Then the task below works as expected

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_list: "{{ my_list|default([]) +
                     [dict(my_range_keys|
                           zip(my_range_keys|
                               map('extract', my_dict)))] }}"
      loop: "{{ my_idxs }}"
      loop_control:
        extended: true
      vars:
#       my_keys: "{{ my_dict.keys()|list|sort }}"
        my_len: "{{ my_keys|length }}"
        my_apps: "{{ my_keys|select('match', '^(\\d+)application(.*)$')|list }}"
        my_idxs: "{{ my_apps|map('regex_replace', '^(\\d+)(.*)$', '\\1')|list }}"
        my_last: "{{ ansible_loop.nextitem|default(my_len|int + 1) }}"
        my_range: "{{ range(item|int - 1, my_last|int - 1)|list }}"
        my_range_keys: "{{ my_range|map('extract', my_keys)|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_list
```

gives

```
  my_list:
  - 1application: abc
    2service: def
    3service: ghi
  - 4application: jkl
    5service: mno
  - 6application: abc
    7service: def
    8service: ghi
  - 10service: stu
    11service: vxy
    9application: prs
```